# .NET : How to PInvoke UpdateProcThreadAttribute

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I am trying to `PInvoke UpdateProcThreadAttribute()` on Windows 7 but my attempts just keep returning FALSE with a Last Win32 Error of 50.

```
Function declaration (from MSDN)

BOOL WINAPI UpdateProcThreadAttribute(
  __inout    LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST lpAttributeList,
  __in       DWORD dwFlags,
  __in       DWORD_PTR Attribute,
  __in       PVOID lpValue,
  __in       SIZE_T cbSize,
  __out_opt  PVOID lpPreviousValue,
  __in_opt   PSIZE_T lpReturnSize
);
```

Here is my attempt at the PInvoke signature:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool UpdateProcThreadAttribute
(
            IntPtr lpAttributeList,
            UInt32 dwFlags,
            ref UInt32 Attribute,
            ref IntPtr lpValue,
            ref IntPtr cbSize,
            IntPtr lpPreviousValue,
            IntPtr lpReturnSize
);
```

Is this declaration sensible? Thanks.

Comment: it is always worth checking http://www.pinvoke.net/ for these type of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems with your declaration but the one that is giving you the not supported error is the Attribute parameter. A DWORD_PTR is not a pointer but rather a pointer sized unsigned integer so rather than ref uint it should be an IntPtr.

The declaration I would use is:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UpdateProcThreadAttribute(
        IntPtr lpAttributeList, uint dwFlags, IntPtr Attribute,
        IntPtr lpValue, IntPtr cbSize, IntPtr lpPreviousValue, 
        IntPtr lpReturnSize);
```

EDIT:

I tried to do this as a comment but it doesn't take to code very well.

For a process handle you need an IntPtr to hold the handle. So you would need something like:

```
IntPtr hProcess //previously retrieved.
IntPtr lpAttributeList //previously allocated using InitializeProcThreadAttributeList and Marshal.AllocHGlobal.

const int PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS = 0x00020000;
IntPtr lpValue = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr.Size); 
Marshal.WriteIntPtr(lpValue, hProcess);
if(UpdateProcThreadAttribute(lpAttributeList, 0, (IntPtr)PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS, lpValue, (IntPtr)IntPtr.Size, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
{
    //do something
}

//Free lpValue only after the lpAttributeList is deleted.
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I updated the signature but still get 50. How do you recommend setting up, say, lpValue to hold the handle of a process. I have it as an IntPtr (pHandle, say) so do I just pass that straight through and for cbSize do something like: IntPtr pSize = (System.IntPtr)(Marshal.SizeOf(pHandle)); ?

Normally my pinvokes are OK, but this one seems particular fiendish. I am very grateful for your response. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks so much. You have helped me nearly get there.. Now I get error 24 (bad length). In your example above you talked about pass IntPtr.Size as the cbSize parameter, whereas in your original post you had this as an IntPtr. I tried IntPtr lpSize = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr.Size); Marshal.WriteInt32(lpSize, IntPtr.Size) and passing that through. Clearly it is wrong but I can't work out what the correct usage should be. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I left out the conversion. It should be (IntPtr)IntPtr.Size. I've corrected the post.